# Big spaces above and below video player

Tags: swift, swiftui, avkit

I have added a video player to play stream video. And now there are some spaces at the top and bottom.

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct LivePageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Top")
            VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url:  URL(string: "https://stream.site.com:1500/hls/stream.m3u8")!))
                .frame(idealHeight: 300)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Text("Bottom")
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

How to delete this spaces?

Comment: and you need top and bottom Text as well? If you remove that the space shouldn’t be there.

Comment: I added Text() only for example.

Comment: remove it and try. I tested on my side it’s now having extra space.You can also use a Ztack.

Comment: If I delete them, the video stretches to full screen. This is right. But my real application has different content on top and bottom. And because of the block with the video, there is a big space at the top that cannot be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the solution of my problem. The problem was in `NavigationView`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                LivePageView()
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is example of correct code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LivePageView()
        }
    }
}
```

Player work's fine.